# Get Count of array that converted to dynamic in c#

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var ints=new List<int> {10,11,22};
      Something(ints);//Output:Count is:3
      Something(new int[10]); //'System.Array' does not contain
                              //  a definition for 'Count'
      Console.ReadLine();     
  }
  static void Something(ICollection collection)
  {
      dynamic dynamic = collection;
      Console.WriteLine("Count is:{0}", dynamic.Count);
  }
```

When pass a List all thing is ok. But when pass array and convert to dynamic i get this error:`'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Count'`.

I know what is my solution but i want to know why compiler has a this behaviors?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: I think interesting thing is `ICollection` has a `Count` property.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Something(new int[10]);

static void Something(ICollection collection)
{
    //The dynamic keyword tells the compilier to look at the underlying information
    //at runtime to determine the variable's type.  In this case, the underlying 
    //information suggests that dynamic should be an array because the variable you
    //passed in is an array.  Then it'll try to call Array.Count.
    dynamic dynamic = collection;
    Console.WriteLine("Count is:{0}", dynamic.Count);

    //If you check the type of variable, you'll see that it is an ICollection because
    //that's what type this function expected.  Then this code will try to call 
    //ICollection.Count
    var variable = collection;
    Console.WriteLine("Count is:{0}", variable.Count);
}
```

Now that we can understand why dynamic.Count is trying to call System.Array.Count.  However, it's still unclear why Array.Count is not defined when Array implements System.Collections.ICollection which has a Count method.  Array does in fact implement ICollection correctly, and it does have a Count method.  However, consumers of Array.Count do not have permission to access the Count property without explicitly casting the Array to an ICollection. Array.Count is implemented with a pattern known as [explicit interface implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx) where  Array.Count is explicitly implemented for ICollection.  And you may only access the count method by  casting your variable to an ICollection with this pattern.  This is reflected in the [docs for Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).  Look for the "Explicit Interface Implementations" section.

```
var myArray = new int[10];
//Won't work because Array.Count is implemented with explicit interface implementation
//where the interface is ICollection
Console.Write(myArray.Count);
//Will work because we've casted the Array to an ICollection
Console.Write(((ICollection)myArray).Count);
```

Comment: I understand it but I don't know if the OP will, a code example would help.

Comment: It is to do with [Explicit interface implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx). You have to cast object to an interface reference to access the interface's property/method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, writing a more thorough answer now

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic works internally using reflection.  The array class does not have a property Count.  It has a property Length which explicitly implements the ICollection property Count.  This means that when you try to do the dynamic invocation, it fails, because it can not find a matching property.

My question for you would be why are you trying to use dynamic in this case -- you've already limited it to classes that support an interface, at that point you should be using the interface (which would work).  At this point you're pretty much guaranteed to be able to get an enumerator and the count -- nothing else.  If you need more, consider a better interface.

Comment: I think the OP knows he shouldn't be using `dynamic` here.  I think he's more curious as to why he's seeing this behavior because he says "I know what is my solution but i want to know why compiler has a this behaviors."

Comment: @StevenWexler: Which is why I pointed out that it works via reflection.  In the compiled code, it uses the string "Count" to look for the appropriate method, but Array doesn't have a method "Count", it has a method "Length" which implements the interface ICollection.Count.  My point was that the OP should either use the interface, or if dynamic is really needed, have the parameter be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

"I know what is my solution but i want to know why compiler has a this behaviors?"

For your question, as I know the compiler behavior is..
The compiler doesn't handle the dynamic type variable at compile-time, because the dynamic type is handled at the run-time. That's why that error appears.

If you want the compiler to handle this case, you can change your **dynamic** type into **var** type.

in a short words.. the dynamic type variable is not the compiler's responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the name of the property is **not** `Count`, but rather `System.Collections.ICollection.get_Count`.

If you run

```
foreach (var item in typeof(int[]).GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                              BindingFlags.Public    |
                                              BindingFlags.Instance))
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

you will get back

```
...
System.Collections.ICollection.get_Count
...
```

which is because the interface is implemented explicitly.